# How to structure and handle data of Firebase realtime database that contains cross-objects ID references?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js

**Context**: Nuxt SPA with TypeScript. Connected to Firebase Realtime Database. Using Nuxt/Firebase Module. I have four data objects in my Firebase Realtime Database. They contain ID references to each other. Let's, for example, look at the design of three of the data objects.

```
"projects":
  {
    "p1" : 
      {
        "projectTeam": {
          "0": "t1",
          "1": "t2",
          "2": "t3",
        },
        "courseId" : "c1",
        "objective": "The objective of the project",
        "someOtherKey": "withSomeValue"
      }
  }
```

```
"courses":
  {
    "c1" : 
      {
        "name" : "The name of course A",
        "someOtherKey": "withSomeValue"
      },
    "c2" : 
      {
        "name" : "The name of course B",
        "someOtherKey": "withSomeValue"
      }
  }
```

```
"teamMembers" :
  {
    "t1" : 
      {
        "name": "John",
        "expertise": "Some expertise"
      },
    "t2" : 
      {
        "name": "Jane",
        "expertise": "Some other expertise"
      },
    "t3" : 
      {
        "name": "George",
        "expertise": "Some other expertise"
      }
  }
```

**Objective**: I need to 'resolve' all the data references before I render the data in my SPA. In other words, I try to get, for example:

```
"projects":
  {
    "p1" : 
      {
        "projectTeamNames": {
          "0": "John",
          "1": "Jane",
          "2": "George",
        },
        "courseName": "The name of course A",
        "objective": "The objective of the project",
        "someOtherKey": "withSomeValue"
      }
  }
```

**Tried**: Fetch all four data objects from Firebase inside a `beforeMount()` life cycle hook and resolve the references immediately after (still inside the hook).

```
beforeMount () {
  let  projects = []
  const courses = []

  {
    const REF = this.$fire.database.ref( 'projects' )
    REF.on( 'child_added', snapshot => {
      projects.push({ id: snapshot.key, ...snapshot.val() })
    })
  }
  {
    const REF = this.$fire.database.ref( 'courses' )
    REF.on( 'child_added', snapshot => {
      courses.push({ id: snapshot.key, ...snapshot.val() })
    })
  }

  const getCourseName = project => {
    const course = courses.find( course => course.id === project.courseId )
    return course.name
  }

  projects = projects.map( project => (
    {
      ...project,
      courseName: getCourseName(project)
    }
  ))

  // Some more handling of ID references

  this.projects = projects

}
```

Although this approach does not throw any errors, if I render projects inside the DOM with `{{ projects }}`, the rendered data object does not have a property `courseName`.

I have been struggling with handling these ID references in combination with a Firebase Realtime Database, and I could use some insight into how to code this -- and, especially, how to code this according to good practices. My mind wonders to hacky solutions, but I would like to learn the proper way forward.

I want to follow the [official advice](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) to avoid nesting inside the data objects, but fail to see how to then resolve the ID references.

**Specific questions**:

1. Is a Firebase Realtime Database suited for storing data objects that reference each other's properties the way I mentioned?
2. Is there any way to resolve the ID references on the Firebase side? Or do I need to resolve the ID references inside my SPA?
3. I tried resolving an ID reference in a `beforeMount()` hook (see code block above). Why can't I add a property to my fetched data, like so:

```
// THIS CODE IS PART OF PREVIOUS CODE BLOCK. SEE THAT CODE BLOCK FOR CONTEXT
const getCourseName = project => {
  const course = courses.find( course => course.id ===  project.courseId )
  return course.name
}

projects = projects.map( project => (
  {
    ...project,
    courseName: getCourseName(project)
  }
))
```

Do I need to deep clone the data object inside my SPA first? Or am I not thinking into the right direction? What is the right way to resolve the ID references?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I exactly understand the question, but some general observations:

- You seem to have done a decent job already flattening your data structure. At first glance, all I'd change was to take `projectTeam` out of each project and make it a top-level list (with the project ID as the key), so that you can load project details without its team and vice versa.
- I'd probably use `on('value')` (or `once('value'` or `get()`) instead of `on('child_added'` as it'll be easier to control the flow that way (you'll typically handle multiple `child_added` events on startup, where with `once('value'` or `get()` you'll get all data in one go).
- Listening for the complete value events means you can replace the existing `projects` and `courses` array contents with what you get from the database.
- If you continue to handle `child_added`, consider whether you should also handle the other `child_` event types.

---

> 1. Is a Firebase Realtime Database suited for storing data objects that reference each other's properties the way I mentioned?

You can store the IDs of objects to link them together, but there's no specific type for such IDs. So in the database level itself, they are just values and not links.

If you want to enforce referential integrity, you can (sometimes only partially) do that in [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

> 2. Is there any way to resolve the ID references on the Firebase side? Or do I need to resolve the ID references inside my SPA?

Firebase doesn't support server-side joins, so you will have to get the data from the linked objects in your application code.

> 3. ...

It's hard to say, but my educated guess is that you may be calling `getCourseName` before the `courses` have loaded. I recommend logging `courses.length` in `getCourseName` to verify that, or (almost always the best way to create a better understanding) setting breakpoints and running in your browser's debugger.

Comment: I'll edit the post to make my question explicit.

Comment: In order:
1. I see. That makes sense, also now I think back to the recommendation in the official documentation about denormalizing.
2. and 3. I decided to use `child_added` so all the data is fetched on page load and any user added children will be pushed to all users. But also I wanted to add the id key-value pair to the children. That was my reasoning, but I'll study your recommendation.
4. Yes. Ultimately I want to establish a full sync between database and what users see.

Comment: I think part of my confusion has to do with the fact that I don't have a good enough grasp of asynchronous programming in JS. If I understand correctly, any `on()` or `once()` of Firebase returns a promise and those need to be handled properly, otherwise I'll run into `undefined` errors.

Comment: `once` and `get` return a promise, `on` doesn't as it can be called multiple times and a promise only resolves once. --- I also added answers to your 3 questions.